# Thinnest font in Java

Tags: java, fonts, font-size

would like to know which Font is the thinnest in Java. I have limited space to show the characters so I would like to take the most thin font.

I mean given a font size, which font takes the minimal space in x-dimension. that should be clear now.

Comment: By thin do you mean less height?

Comment: You mean, that's still readable? You could draw your own raster font (5x3 or mostly-5x3)

Comment: Where are you showing these characters?

Comment: @JanDvorak good point - a 1x1 font would be the smallest if there are absolutely no other constraints.  Which sounds flippant but highlights a relevant point, that there is a trade off here against other criteria that are loosely defined.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Good point. A 1x1 font is _technically_ still readable. Just assign a different color to each character - but it would be extremely hard to read.

Comment: `Times` and `Sceptre` look thinner than `Times New Roman`, but I doubt many will have them.

Comment: `Marigold` is very thin given a line height, but it's not very readable.

Comment: `Aurora Cn BT` is extremely thin

Comment: @JanDvorak - it would be better to say "theoretically" readable, I think.  In reality, the human eye could not distinguish the colours reliably enough ... even assuming it was possible to display the colour of a 1x1 pixel that accurately on a typical display.

Comment: @StephenC assuming a text-only font, that would be "just" 27 colors. A human eye can easily distinguish the colors even if they were all shades of gray. If we assume color output, the human brain should be able to reliably distinguish all of them. Even if we assume ASCII, that would be 3 bits for green and 2 bit for red and blue. The human eye can catch that. Of course, you have effects such as the effect of sub-pixels not overlapping. So yes, "theoretically" might be a better word.

Comment: @JanDvorak - *"The human eye can catch that."* - even if we restrict it to only 27 distinct colours, I doubt that the AVERAGE adult's eyes would be be good enough to do that RELIABLY for ONE-PIXEL symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a large list of font examples:
http://www.wavian.com/font-list.html

My picks are:

- `Aurora Cn BT` - not very readable but it IS thin.
- `English 111 Vivace BT` is very thin and readable cursive unless you use a lot of uppercase.
- `Coronet` is extremely thin and similar to `English 111 Vivace BT`
- `Marigold` is not as thin, but it might be more readable
- `Onyx` and `OzHandicraft` are both very thin and readable
- `Ribbon 131 Bd BT`
- `Sceptre` and `Socket` - thin and readable

Answer (score 0):

Your Java will use system font so there is no such thing as thinnest Java font. Look at your font list and see which one is the thinnest. Ariel is your best bet I think.

Comment: Arial is not the thinnest. Keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously scale fonts down to make them as "thin" as you like but that probably won't be readable with regular fonts.

You best bet is probably to find a custom font that is specifically designed for a very low resolution (5x3, 6x4 or 8x5 fonts might be appropriate). You can then include your custom font as a resource in your Java project.